# Spring Batch Parameter conversion unclear

Tags: java, spring-batch

When I run a job with the new Spring Batch 5 RC1, it comes always to the following error:

org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [my.package.FileProvider] to type [java.lang.String]

So, it seems that I need to provide a `GenericConverter`. But the standard ways aren't working.

If I register them via:

```
    @Configuration
    public class ConverterRegistration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
            registry.addConverter(new FileConverter<>());
            registry.addConverterFactory(new FileConverterFactory());
        }
    }
```

it doesn't work. And even if I extend `DefaultBatchConfiguration` and set the converter in a `@PostConstruct` method with calls like `getConversionService().addConverter(new FileConverter())`,
my debugger shows that the list of converters stays always the same, at the point where the exception comes from: `GenericConversionService`. It seems that the Jobs have their own local list of converters. A first stop at a breakpoint shows that `GenericConversionService` has 129 converters, including my custom ones, and at a later stop, when the exceptions gets thrown, it has always 52 converters.

How do I add a converter there?

At the JobBuilder?

```
    return new JobBuilder(JOB_IMPORT, jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(infoImport)
                .end()
                .build();
```

At the step builder?

```
    new StepBuilder(getStepName(), jobRepository)
         .<I, O>chunk(chunkSize, platformTransactionManager)
         .listener(readListener)
         .reader(reader)
         .processor(processor)
         .writer(writer)
```

Most likely the job parameters, but how?

```
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addJobParameter(FILE_PROVIDER,
                        new JobParameter<>(fileProvider, FileProvider.class))
                .addString(INFO_FILE_NAME, fileInfo)
                .toJobParameters();
    jobLauncher.run(fileImportJob, jobParameters);
```

Can somebody show me where and how I can set my custom `GenericConverter`?
Or is it somehow a `JobParametersConverter` which is needed, but then: How to set *that*
(the documentation at [Spring Batch 5 RC1, Java Config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/5.0.0-RC1/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig/html/job.html#javaConfig) seems incomplete)?

Comment: Do you really need the `FileProvider` as a parameter? Parameters get persisted into the database and thus converted to a string. Nonetheless the web based converters aren't used by SPring Batch (AFAIK) so you would need to configure that one instead of the mvc one. Also Spring Batch 5 isn't final yet and a work-in-progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no relation between web converters and batch converters. You should not be expecting that converters registered through `WebMvcConfigurer` are going to be used by Spring Batch.

> And even if I extend DefaultBatchConfiguration and set the converter in a @PostConstruct method with calls like getConversionService().addConverter(new FileConverter()),

This won't work as `getConversionService()` always return a new instance of `DefaultConversionService`. You need to override `DefaultBatchConfiguration#getConversionService` and return the instance of the conversion service you want to use for your job parameters, including all your converters. Here is a typical example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyJobConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        // define your job
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected ConfigurableConversionService getConversionService() {
        DefaultConversionService conversionService = new DefaultConversionService();
        // add converters to conversionService
        return conversionService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it, pretty obvious once you see it. Override `DefaultBatchConfiguration#getConversionService()`, like this:

```
    @Override
    protected ConfigurableConversionService getConversionService() {
        ConfigurableConversionService conversionService = super.getConversionService();
        conversionService.addConverter(new MyOwnConverter<>());
        return conversionService;
    }
```